# Is it possible to have some kind of mechanism in place which forces the developer to write Junit Test cases for all the methods in a class ?

Tags: java, junit4

I was wondering if there can be some kind of component(eg: a custom annotation ) developed which will force a developer to write Junit test cases for all the methods in a class.
Apologies if it sounds ridiculous . Just wanted to make sure if i'm thinking in the rigth direction. Any suggestions are welcome 
Thanks in advance

Comment: some kind of management structure and code reviews ?

Comment: Use [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), and force the developers to do so by taking managerial actions against people who breach the rule.

Comment: you can use eclemma to check code coverage. This is what I do, not full proof, but definitely a way to make sure that your code testing is of a high standard. Saying that, all it checks is that your code got hit, so it is upto you to write good tests ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm aware of some of these code coverage tools and definitely make it a point to explore the ones that i'm not. To my understanding all these tools are to diagnose the severeity of the problem and i was thinking if we can preverent the problem itself :) . My idea is ,if we can write a custom annotation say @WriteJunits and if a class is annotated with it then  all methods in that class must have Junit test cases. I'm sure even if this worked there's no way to enforce the quality of tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a code coverage tool like [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) ? You can configure this to enforce a certain coverage level and fail the build if this is not enforced (see end of linked article).

It won't enforce the quality of tests however, and a wholey automated system won't solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code is written by people. 
All the coverage tools in the world is not going to change that.

The path I would take is making sure your developers are not writing Unit tests because they have to, but make sure they feel responsible for the code they write.

Comment: I completely agree with your point. I'm just trying to see if i can develop something of the sort which enforces the developers. That should be a good learning experience for me.